# declaring a vector with class items in it

Tags: c++, class, vector

how to declare a vector that has all the elements in class in it? for example:

```
class Book{
    string name;
    int published;
    float price;
}
```

would a vector be in a class or just in a main function? Declare it as `vector<Book *> a`;
how could you then add those names in this vector? what if you have more than one book, you would have to declare a new vector?

Comment: A `std::vector` is just a container. I suggest you declare it as `std::vector<Book> a;` and forget about pointers unless you have a _compelling_ reason to `new` the objects yourself.

Comment: A vector in normal language could be described as a list, therefore a vector<Book> - could be described as a 'list of books'. However in STL we have a list also and many other data structures that are called collections. I suspect you need to find some basic tutorials before you start to use things like this...

Comment: Instead of asking "How do I use `vector`?" try describing the problem you are having that you think `vector` might solve? Then we can guide you to the best solution.

Comment: basically I wanna do an inventory program

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you are asking. If you want a vector of Books, then `vector<Book>` will do the trick. At this time, I advise against using pointers since that introduces some other complexities. Each Book in the vector contains its own elements as you have declared them.

A vector is one way to keep track of more than one book. You only need to declare another vector if you need two **lists** of books to keep track of (for example, one vector is a list of non-fiction books and the other is a list of fiction books).

Where you declare a vector depends on how you want to use it. To start, you probably want to declare it in `main` to test that it works. If you later want to create a `Library` class, then you will most likely declare `vector<Book>` inside that class.

Comment: how can you access the data using the vector then? Like what if you want to change the price of the specific book

Comment: @JackF Back up for a moment. If you declared `Book b`, do you know how to access the data inside the Book object? Next, given `vector<Book>` (and assume that it has 10 books stored in it), do you know how to get the 5th book in the vector? If you can do both of those, it is only a short jump to finish answering your question.

Comment: using iterator to get to the 5th book,

Comment: @JackF that is one way. The only problem is what if you want to get the 100th book or the millionth book in a large vector? Using an iterator is slow. Do you know any other way of accessing elements in a vector?

Comment: @JackF Also, you skipped my first question. You need to know how to access data inside of a Book object before moving on to accessing Book objects in a vector.

Comment: so you can access the data like b[3] for example?

Comment: I'm just confused about how it will know the second book for example you have vector<Book> a; which means it is empty, so you can assign the tree values vector<Book> a(somename,2012,$3.00)?

Comment: You are correct that the initial vector will be empty. You need to find a way to add `Book` objects to the `vector`. What you have given in the comment is incorrect, though. Read up on the `vector` class to figure out the correct way to do it. If you get stuck, please come back and let us know where you have checked.

Comment: [cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/) is a good overall site for technical reference about the Standard Library. You will need to look elsewhere for introductory tutorials.

Answer (score 0):

> would a vector be in a class or just in a main function?

It doesn't make much sense. std::vector is a class container that can hold several elements (all of the same type) inside it.

> Declare it as `vector<Book *> a`

Note that this way you are declaring a vector of pointers to classes.

> how could you then add those names in this vector?

You can use [std::vector::push_back](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stl/vector/push_back/) to insert elements at the end of the vector.

> what if you have more than one book, you would have to declare a new
>   vector?

Well, that's exactly the reason to use a container like vector, holding multiple elements. Having more vectors doesn't make sense.

> how can you access the data using the vector then? Like what if you
>   want to change the price of the specific book

Just to keep it simple, you can use brackets to access an element of the vector at the given index. In C++ class member are private by default, if you don't declare them explicitely public. So, avoiding further explanations (see getter/setter for an eventually better design), an approach could be the following:

```
class Book{

    public:

    string name;
    int published;
    float price;

    Book (string iName, int iPublished, float iPrice)
    {
        name = iName;
        published = iPublished;
        price = iPrice;
    }
}

std::vector<Book*> bookList = std::vector();
bookList.push_back(new Book("foo", 10, 100.0f));
bookList.push_back(new Book("bar", 11, 110.0f));

std::cout << bookList[1].name; // print bar
```